# how to install xdebug in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

how to install xdebug in Linux Mint?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a package for it: http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/php5-xdebug

You may not have the package's repository enabled in your package manager.

Answer (score 0):

You may read [this](http://www.xdebug.org/download.php) as well. It is the official xdebug website.